# ffmpeg - Drawtext Fade Out

Tags: ffmpeg

Here is a new question on drawtext; actually, my drawtexts move from the left to right and from right to left, depending on the order ( 1,3,5... from left, 2,4,6 from right).

Each drawtext has a box; it would be nice to have each drawtext disappear with a fade out before other drawtext come in.

I see that there is the "fontcolor_exr", but I don't want to change the color of my text, I'd like to change the alpha, so I suppose I have to play with "alpha" props.
Unfortunatly, I cannot figure out how to set an expression to add the alpha trasparency after x seconds to my drawtext. Any Idea?

I'm trying to use something like this:

```
alpha='if(gt(t,4),--- some expresson --- ,1)'"
```

so that after 4 seconds, the drawtext will disappear.

Thanks

**SOLVED**

I found this graceful solution; let the drawtext be enabled between 0 and 6 seconds; this command will fade out the text after 5 seconds:

alpha='if(lt(t,5)\,1\,if(lt(t\,6)\,(1-(t-5))/1\,0))'

The entire drawbox disappear at second 6. Hope it helps.

See you next time!

Comment: You have to use fontcolor_expr. See 2nd last [example](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Examples-89).

Comment: I read that expression , `fontcolor_expr=ff0000...` but I really don't understand  what does it do, and cause I don't understand it, I cannot apply it  :( ... can you explain me quickly? tks!

Comment: and, sorry,  are you sure that ALL drawtext ( with box and border ) will disappear? I read that it is used to change the confcolor dinamically, while I need to fade the entire drawtext ( text, box, etc ... )  ..

Comment: No, the box, shadow.. won't disappear.